# Proof by Dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

this is an exercise book schaums Theory & Problems of Modern Algebra by Frank Ayres Jr. says: If $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are cuts, then $\mathbf{A}\subset\mathbf{B}$ implies $\mathbf{A}\neq\mathbf{B}$

My hypothesis is that $\mathbf{A,B}$ are cuts

I tried to take an element in $\mathbf{B}$ and prove that does not belong to $\mathbf{A}$, but the definition of cuts I have failed

Comment: What definition of *cut* are you using? And does Ayres use $\subset$ for strict inclusion (i.e., $\subsetneqq$), or for weak inclusion (i.e., $\subseteq$)?

Comment: by a cut $\mathbf{C}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ we shall mean a non-empty proper subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ having the additional properties:

i) If $\mathbf{c}\in\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $\mathbf{a}\lt\mathbf{c}$ then $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbf{C}$

ii)for ever $\mathbf{c}\in\mathbf{C}$ there exists $\mathbf{b}\in\mathbf{C}$ such that $\mathbf{b}\gt\mathbf{c}$

$\mathbb{Q}$:Rational. In exercise is $\mathbf{A}\subsetneq\mathbf{B}$

Comment: Okay; that’s a pretty standard definition of Dedekind cut. The result is true for any sets, not just Dedekind cuts: if $A\subsetneqq B$, then **by definition** there is some $b\in B\setminus A$. (There will of course also be elements of $B$ that *are* in $A$.)